# Do Android and iOS have the ability to power an external device such as a flashlight without an app?

Tags: android, ios

I'm thinking about developing a flashlight that plugs into the charging port and/or the headphones port of an Android and/or iOS device. Will I need to create an app to switch it on and off or more preferably can I have it turn on automatically when plugged in?

Comment: I think You'd be more limited by phone actually supporting external devices, hardware and firmware wise (USB OTG?). Otherwise phone will always assume it's a "slave" and only draw power IN.

Comment: Doing it without an app would require that to be in the software/hardware of the device you plug in.  It wouldn't be due to the phone.  For example headphones work without software because the hardware itself is built to just process signals coming in.  Pass it a signal strong enough, and it produces sound.  A flashlight's hardware could be made to turn on when it detects current over USB.

Comment: Although I'd have to ask-  what's the usecase?  If you want a flashlight, use the flash.  If you want a more powerful/focused light, why attach it to the phone?  Battery?  Batteries are small these days.

Comment: So there is directional current available as long as I have the hardware capability in the device? And it's a special type of flashlight that doesn't use standard white light. Also would the device need to have USB OTG? I think Android 3.1 up have that right?

Comment: There is power available on the lightning port of an iOS device, but to communicate with the device from an app your device will need to be MFi certified unless you use BLE rather than the lightning port itself to communicate